# Crypt() user's ID to be alphanumeric for use in API Request URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encryption, crypt

When a user adds an account to their profile that account will be given an Auto-incremented ID as expected by the database.

I use this ID and then use php's `crypt($account_id, 'salt_here')` function with a custom, static salt to generate a safe, public ID that I don't care if the user sees and then add this to the database for the related account for future use.

This crypted id I want to use in a REST API I'm currently building.

Here's where I am:

- User uses API to get accounts on profile `/v1/accounts/PROFILE_USERNAME`
- Each account result shows crypted_id which I just named as id in the result data (I don't want to show the real ID from the database) `"id": "Mq5RFENsi4/rw"`
- User can then loop through the account data from the API request and get the crypted_id and then make another API request (`/v1/accountSiblings/ACCOUNT_CRYPTED_ID`) `(ACCOUNT_CRYPTED_ID = Mq5RFENsi4/rw)` for further information about the account, for instance, how many siblings the account has.

The problem I have is that `crypt()` does not return alphanumeric results so the data is iffy when passed into the URL for another API request especially considering it can return forward-slashes and other characters I don't want.

Is there another 1-way crypt function I can use that is only alphanumeric to be used as the crypted id?

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Hope I'm clear enough, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 4am so bear with me.

I think it will be just fine for me to simply `md5()` the crypt's output...

It doesn't matter if that md5 hash is decrypted because the end result is basically gobbledegook and is a 1-way hash.

Obvious now that I think about it...